# BundleConfig is bundling the old versions of my CSS files

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with c# in MVC4, and I have a weird issue with my CSS files. 
Everything is working perfectly in localhost. The changes that I do in the CSS file are working. Problem comes when I publish my project to the hosting server, where the bundle file created by BundleConfig.css is the old version.

Here you can see [one of the examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXPL6.jpg):

In my piece of code, there's the new line, and the old one commented.

After that,  you can see the styles in my localhost, and in the end, the styles in the hosting server.

BundleConfing is using the old version where I still have 50px as min-height.

Comment: what is source code of your bundleconfig, and what settings do you use for publishing ?

Comment: Hi Yura and thank you for answering.

Do you need the complete bundleConfig file? or is that enough? :)

Answer (score 1):

Some time it can be caused if you have minimized version of css and not minimized version of css in the same folder.

Let's say you have following structure

```
~/Content/your.css
~/Content/your.min.css
```

in your folder, and you registered the "your.css" file in bundle, then optimizer will try at first to use the "your.min.css" file in time of publishing. If you modified only "your.css" and didn't modify "your.min.css" then you'll get old styles from "your.min.css". You can modify "your.min.css" or remove it. This is not the case during debug because compiler as usually has the following configuration:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <!-- some more lines -->
</system.web>
```

Also you can kill web.config setting with the following line:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

That are my assumptions. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Yura again :)
The case of the minimized version, I think it's not my case because I've tried removing in the bundleConfig the lines where I included those files...and I have the same problem in the hosting server. Regarding web.config, I check my file and I have also debug= true.

I dont't know what to do :(

Comment: what is your publishing settings?

Comment: I publish through VisualStudio and I have in configuration with "release". 
In "File Publish Options", I selected only "removed additional at destination".